# How to create pdf file using Django template with proper CSS?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I am new to Django and stack overflow as well.
I want to create Django template as a pdf file with all CSS styles .I used following code to create pdf file it **renders file content properly but not CSS styles**.

Here is the code I have used :

```
from io import BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    pdf = render_to_pdf("abc.html")
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    else
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use styles in html-template by 2 ways:

1. Use `<style>...</style>` in `head` tag of html-template.
2. Use `.css` file from static assets of your django app. And then add link in  `head` tag of html-template, e.g.:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/abc.css' %}" type="text/css" />`. But in this case you should setup [managing of the static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/).

Some usefull links with examples: [style tag](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/a-beginners-guide-to-generate-pdf-s-with-django-part-1-901e258f0f93), [static css](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files)

But I should mention that not all styles will be applied in output pdf file. I reccomend to use the most simple markup and styles.